# localStorage Isn't Accessible in Chrome's --single-process Mode

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, chromium

So I'm trying* to use Chromium's `--single-process` flag (yes, *I know* it's the most dangerous thing in the world, etc., no need for a lecture, thanks!) with `localStorage`, and for some reason, it looks like whenever Chromiums is started in single-process mode, `localStorage` no longer has any data accessible from it.

What's the reason behind this? And is there any way to get around it?

(If that means recompiling Chromium, let me know what I need to modify where.)

Comment: Never used that flag before but the documentation states that this mode may contain severall bugs. It further says that worker-threads are spawned into separate processes. There may be a bug that prevents a worker in another process from communicating with your process. If the local-storage is accessed by that worker you won't get any results. Have you tried storing data first and then retrieving the stored data in single-process mode? The storage may just live elsewhere in single-process mode.

Comment: @marsbear: If I store the data and then retrieve it again, it works, but it's not persistent: they're gone when I close Chromium and open it again.

Comment: Sounds like some other problem. Maybe it is by intention as single-process is just a test-feature.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to search for some results about your issue, so I`v entered the irc (on freenode, #chromium channel) and because **rsleevi** don't have account I just copied our conversation:

Me:

> hey, does anyone knows about Chromium's "--single-process" and localstorage bug ?

rsleevi:

> <+rsleevi> That's a bit of a broad
>   question. But the easy answer is
>   "--single-process" isn't a "supported"
>   flag - it truly is intended for
>   debugging purposes only by devs. If
>   you're using/relying on it for general
>   use, then theres your problem :)
>   <+rsleevi> It's reasonably expected
>   that a number of things won't work or
>   won't work right in --single-process

Me:

> yes I understand that is for debugging
>   pupposes, but I just want to know why
>   localStorage doesn't work well while
>   other stuff does :)

rsleevi:

> <+rsleevi> Well, the answer is because
>   --single-process isn't "supported" :-) [13:58:32] <+rsleevi> The design of
>   new features always designs for the
>   multi-process scenario. If it happens
>   to work in --single-process,
>   serendipity, if not, c'est le vie

Me:

> OK I understand. Just thought maybe
>   there is some "offical why"

rsleevi:

> <+rsleevi> Generally, no, there's not
>   some decision "We don't want to
>   support X in --single-process"... It's
>   "X doesn't happen to work? Oh well"
>
> <+rsleevi> If you're using
>   --single-process, realize that (just like the info bar says) you're running
>   without all the nice security
>   features, and your
>   configuration/features are expected to
>   regularly break or be unusable. I
>   really can't stress the
>   "not-supported" aspect enough, in the
>   hope that maybe I can sway you :-)

Me:

> I don't know if you are a memeber on
>   stackoverflow, but I`m trying to help
>   this mate here:
>   [localStorage Isn't Accessible in Chrome's --single-process Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925349/localstorage-isnt-accessible-in-chromes-single-process-mode)
>   , maybe you can answer his question (
>   if you  are a member ) 
>   Don't want to take your copyrights :)

rsleevi:

> [14:09:57] <+rsleevi> Heh. I don't
>   have an account, sounds like your mate
>   doesn't want my lecture, but the
>   answer is just like the info bar says
>   "unsupported" :-) marsbear's second
>   answer is right on track - it's just a
>   development aide [14:10:08] <+rsleevi>
>   that is, Chromium development, not
>   general webdev

I know that there isn't a fully answer here, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: +1 for trying to be so helpful, and you'll probably get the bounty award unless someone else figures out the actual answer with regards to the code. :) Thanks for all this effort, I appreciate it!